# Microsoft Graph API OneNote pages content BadRequest

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am using OneNote `/content` endpoint to retrieve page content as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

However, calling `GET` on `/me/onenote/pages/{id}/content[?includeIDs=true]` returns me this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'content['.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6b7e5549-32a5-4b6f-80ed-ecacp9v41699",
            "date": "2020-03-31T00:05:27"
        }
    }
}
```

calling `GET` on `/me/onenote/pages/{id}/content` returns this:

```
{
  "_readableState": {
    "objectMode": false,
    "highWaterMark": 16384,
    "buffer": {
      "head": null,
      "tail": null,
      "length": 0
    },
    "length": 0,
    "pipes": [],
    "flowing": null,
    "ended": false,
    "endEmitted": false,
    "reading": false,
    "sync": false,
    "needReadable": false,
    "emittedReadable": false,
    "readableListening": false,
    "resumeScheduled": false,
    "errorEmitted": false,
    "emitClose": true,
    "autoDestroy": false,
    "destroyed": false,
    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
    "awaitDrainWriters": null,
    "multiAwaitDrain": false,
    "readingMore": false,
    "decoder": null,
    "encoding": null
  },
  "readable": true,
  "_events": {},
  "_eventsCount": 5,
  "_writableState": {
    "objectMode": false,
    "highWaterMark": 16384,
    "finalCalled": false,
    "needDrain": false,
    "ending": false,
    "ended": false,
    "finished": false,
    "destroyed": false,
    "decodeStrings": true,
    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
    "length": 0,
    "writing": false,
    "corked": 0,
    "sync": true,
    "bufferProcessing": false,
    "writecb": null,
    "writelen": 0,
    "afterWriteTickInfo": null,
    "bufferedRequest": null,
    "lastBufferedRequest": null,
    "pendingcb": 0,
    "prefinished": false,
    "errorEmitted": false,
    "emitClose": true,
    "autoDestroy": false,
    "errored": false,
    "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
    "corkedRequestsFree": {
      "next": null,
      "entry": null
    }
  },
  "writable": true,
  "allowHalfOpen": true,
  "_transformState": {
    "needTransform": false,
    "transforming": false,
    "writecb": null,
    "writechunk": null,
    "writeencoding": null
  }
}
```

Neither returns the actual page content. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The "includeIDs" is an optional query parameter. Remove the square brackets around it to get rid of the Bad Request error. So the request should be GET on /me/onenote/pages/{id}/content?includeIDs=true

Comment: Did that. It's giving me the same response as `/me/onenote/pages/{id}/content` which is just the Binary data